# bash: Using param in find function filling an array

Tags: arrays, bash, find, parameter-passing

I am searching for files via a script. To work with the result, find is filling an array with the results. I am traying it this way

```
RANGE=$1
arr=( $(find /net/nas3/mediadata/xmlprodpictures/tui ! -iname "* *" -iregex '.*/big/[${RANGE}]/.*\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)' -type f | sort) )
```

it is not working, while it does if i am setting the params directly in the line.

A problem of correct escaping?

THX in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `readarray` instead:

```
RANGE=$1
readarray -t ARR < <(find /net/nas3/mediadata/xmlprodpictures/tui ! -iname "* *" -iregex ".*/big/[${RANGE}]/.*"'\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)' -type f | sort)
printf "Value: %s\n" "${ARR[@]}"
```

Comment: Not really working, independant of the param i always get the same result :-( even finds result in different folders.

Comment: @MichaEl Sorry. I changed the quoting of some parts to `""`. Please try again.